# How can my perl script receive SNMP traps from a managed system?

Tags: perl, snmp, net-snmp

I would like to do the following, but I'm not sure I'm using the best method:

A perl script, running on a Sparc/Solaris 10 machine, should wait for incoming SNMP trap packets (on port 162 for instance). When it receives a trap, it should decode it and do some processing on it, and then resume waiting for the next trap.

I've looked into Net::SNMP by David M. Town, but I think it only allows sending requests and receiving responses. I can't find a method to wait for spontaneous trap messages in this documentation:
http://search.cpan.org/dist/Net-SNMP/lib/Net/SNMP.pm

The Net-SNMP package, on the other hand, seems like a very robust and well-used library, but even there the documentation does not provide me with a clear path. SNMP::TrapSession allows me to send traps, but not receive them (?).

Some googling leads me to suggestiongs that I should use the "snmptrapd" binary and use the embedded perl functions of it, to call my script when snmptrapd receives a message. This could work, but would be impractical since the embedded perl option requires a perl binary compiled without large file support. I do not own the target system and hence cannot replace the compiler/interpreter. I could ship my software with a specially-compiled perl, but that would give me cross-platform issues I was hoping to avoid.

The reason I'm using Perl and not Java with SNMP4J or similar, is that I have legacy perl code which has previously depended on HP NNM's perl API, and I need to move to a free software back-end to eliminate the license cost.

Comment: After en email to the net-snmp-users mailing list, I've learned that this function in fact does not exist in net-snmp's Perl API. The recommendation I got was to use the supplied snmptrapd program and have my script parse its text output. This would surely work, but I would prefer to have access to the raw BER data and I'm not keen on taking the possible performance hit of parsing text data.
Most likely, I'll go with the Snmp4j option - a language switch might not be a big problem.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, I ended up going the Java route. A simple 2-thread setup works fine: Producer listens to incoming traps via Snmp4j, and puts them on a queue. Consumer (in separate thread) reads the queue on a FIFO basis and does processing. I am able to squeeze just about 400 traps per second into this without dropping anything on the network side.
In contrast, I cannot get snmptrapd (net-snmp) to accept more than 10-50 traps per second, which is a dealbreaker in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple example of using Perl library [SNMP_Session.pm](http://code.google.com/p/snmp-session/) for parsing SNMP traps: [Essential SNMP - page 194](http://books.google.com/books?id=65_0d25EpB4C&lpg=PT210&ots=HXxUymQiiM&dq=SNMPv1_Session-%3Eopen_trap_session&pg=PT210#v=onepage&q=SNMPv1_Session-%3Eopen_trap_session&f=false).

Comment: Thank you! I'll accept this answer because you were first to point me to SNMP_Session lib.

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a library routine to receive *and* parse the packet? Can you listen for UDP packets yourself and then pass any packets you receive to the snmp library to parse them? That's what I'm doing, though I am using python rather than perl.

Comment: Preferably I would not have to deal with raw UDP data and filter out SNMP packets myself. That would be more work than having a lib do it. ;) But yeah, that should be possible, every SNMP lib I've looked at has functions to encode / decode BER data, it's just the "blocking listen" function I've been missing.

Answer (score 2):

If you get the SNMP_Session library (which is entirely Perl btw) you can do things like this:

```
my $trap_session = SNMPv1_Session->open_trap_session ();
my ($trap, $sender_addr, $sender_port) = $trap_session->receive_trap ();
my @blah = $trap_session->decode_trap_request ($trap)
```

Comment: I assume that $trap_session->receive_trap() is a blocking call? That looks like just what I've been looking for. Thanks!